# How to connecting the nodes when Parity starting

Tags: parity, proof-of-authority, enode

I follow this [tutorial](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Demo-PoA-tutorial) to run the PoA demo on Parity.

And when I try to connect the nodes. I found that should do everytime after Parity started.

Can I connect them when I starting Parity? I found that the enode seems change everytime when I start the Parity...

By the way, the PoA will create block continuously though I don't send any transaction? I don't know clearly about it... Thanks a lot~ :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a [PoA network](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Demo-PoA-tutorial) running with 5 clients on `mySpec.json` chain configuration. You can see the public addresses (`enode`s) after starting Parity:

- `enode://0000..0001@192.168.178.101:36541`
- `enode://0000..0002@192.168.178.102:36542`
- `enode://0000..0003@192.168.178.103:36543`
- `enode://0000..0004@192.168.178.104:36544`
- `enode://0000..0005@192.168.178.105:36545`

Add these nodes to a file, let's say `myPoAnetwork.txt`, one entry per line:

```
enode://0000..0001@192.168.178.101:36541
enode://0000..0002@192.168.178.102:36542
enode://0000..0003@192.168.178.103:36543
enode://0000..0004@192.168.178.104:36544
enode://0000..0005@192.168.178.105:36545
```

Make sure the IPs contain either the public address, or if running locally, the LAN address, but not the localhost or loop. And subsequently, run Parity with `--chain mySpec.json --reserved-peers myPoAnetwork.txt`. Or add it to the config file:

```
[parity]
chain = "./mySpec.json"

[network]
reserved_peers = "./myPoAnetwork.txt"
```

This will establish a PoA network automatically adding your nodes:

```
--reserved-peers FILE        Provide a file containing enodes, one per line.
                             These nodes will always have a reserved slot on top
                             of the normal maximum peers. (default: None)
```