# admin.addPeer not working on private blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, javascript

I'm having so much trouble getting geth to talk to a private blockchain of Parity nodes.  Here is where I am right now:

I have fired up geth with a custom data director and a genesis file that think should be a match for the Parity chain spec file.

But geth does not detect the Parity peers.  So I add them manually using the JS console.  The command returns "true" but then admin.peers shows no peers.

```
> admin.addPeer("enode:<string>:<port>")
true

> admin.peers
[]
```

Can anyone think of why this might be?

Comment: There is no `admin` module in Parity. Just use `reserved-peers`. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/25384

Comment: @5chdn I am not asking about Parity.  My question is about geth.  I am trying to get that geth node to connect to a network of Parity nodes.

Comment: I'm sorry, this somehow showed up in my parity filters :)

Comment: Are you sure you want to connect to a peer in the right network? Maybe `--datadir` wasn't set correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Can you make sure when you use `admin.addPeer()` both the above instances are running?

You can either use `geth instance` or `geth console`. (use `ipc: ~your datadir/...` after the above command if your ipc is in a non-default folder).

Also if both these two nodes are on the same machine, you can use 127.0.0.1 as the IP address if the external IP address doesn't work.

Give it try and let me know.

Comment: Good ideas but the problem is that I was trying to do the impossible.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this is that geth isn't going to connect to the private Parity network I was trying.  Here is a really great answer:

[geth not connecting to private network](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16866/geth-not-connecting-to-private-network?noredirect=1#comment26799_16866)